# Открытие приложения пользователем с установленными ранее настройками

Tags: c#

Помогите с реализацией идеи пожалуйста на c# windows forms.
Суть такова:

Пользователь установил себе приложение. Запускает его; при первом запуске появляется окно с выбором его должности, например: повар 1 категории, повар 2 категории, повар 3 категории и т.п. Открывается выбранное окно, к примеру повар 2 категории. (Выбранное окно сохраняется Куда нибудь в настройки пользователя). Пользователь поработал и закрыл программу.

При следующем запуске программы считываются настройки и открывается сразу окно повара 2 категории.
Возможность в будущем поменять в настройках при необходимости с повара 2 категории на повара 1 категории.

Comment: Конкретизируйте вопрос. Вы не знаете, как сохранять настройки в файл, в каком формате сохранять и как это потом считать, или что-то другое?

Comment: Указать как лучше сохранить настройку. И как сделать так что бы При первом запуске программы был выбор. А со второго запуска запускалась выбранный пользователем форма.

Comment: Почитайте что-то вроде "работа с файлами в с#" если хотите сохранять в файл. Если хотите сохранять не в файл - по почитайте как с ним работать.

Comment: Способов сохранения настроек - масса, например, в файл App.config, в базу данных, в свой файл и т.д. 
Я бы разбил вашу задачу на 2: 

1. Определиться, что именно сохранять? 
2. Как именно сохранять?

Comment: Про сохранение настроек почитал. Назовем формы 1 повар 1povar.cs, 2 повар 2.cs сохраним их в файл под переменной formPovarStart. Как теперь в program.cs указать чтение настроек и какую форму загружать? И как при первом запуске загружалпсь форма с выбором открытия формы поваров по умолчанию?

Comment: Вот так можно создать форму: `Form newForm = new Form();`, затем ее показать: `newForm.Show();`. Вам осталось лишь создать _нужную_ форму в зависимости от выбора, сохраненного в настройках. 
А вообще мне почему-то кажется, что вы не с того начали.

Answer (score 1):

Кратко о работе с файлами. Рассмотрим примитивное консольное приложение:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace playground
{
    class Program
    {
        //Допустим, категория просто определяется цифрой (1 - Повар первой категории, и т.п.)?
        //которую мы для простоты будем хранить в виде строки (т.е. в текстовом виде)
        public static string Category;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Если файла с настройками нет - условно, первый запуск приложения
            if (!File.Exists("settings.txt"))
            {
                //
                Console.Write("Укажите категорию повара: ");
                //Пользователь вводит цифру, обозначающую категорию
                Category = Console.ReadLine();

                //...И, собственно, сохраняем её в файл
                File.WriteAllText("settings.txt", Category);          
            }
            //Файл с настройками найден, читаем из него данные
            else
            {
                Category = File.ReadAllText("settings.txt");
            }

            //После того, как пользователь указал категорию (если это первый запуск), или программа считала её из файла (если не первый), выведем информацию в консоль:
            Console.WriteLine($"Повар {Category} категории");

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Строка `using System.IO;` обязательна, она, скажем так, открывает вам доступ к методам работы с файлами (помимо прочего).

Далее обратите внимание на `if (!File.Exists("settings.txt"))` - здесь мы проверяем наличие файла "settings.txt". Вообще, в качестве аргумента передаётся полный путь к файлу (можно [использовать переменные среды](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables(v=vs.110).aspx)), в данном случае он проверяет наличие файла рядом с программой (в той же папке).

Если файл не найден, то пользователю предлагается ввести номер: `Category = Console.ReadLine();`, который тут же записывается в файл: `File.WriteAllText("settings.txt", Category);

Если файл уже есть, программа просто считывает номер из файла: `Category = File.ReadAllText("settings.txt");`

Повторюсь, данный пример очень примитивный. Ознакомтесь [с руководством](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.file(v=vs.110).aspx), записывать в файл можно, разумеется, гораздо более сложные структуры, чем просто значение одной переменной.

В целом, как уже заметили в комментариях, есть огромное множество способов хранить данные программы, простая запись в файл - далеко не единственный.

Comment: Спасибо. Начинаю понимать,а windows forms не могли бы написать пример пожалуйста.

Comment: А в чём проблема? Примерно так же: нет файла - открывается форма выбора, есть - считываете из него категорию, показываете соответствующую информацию. Если вы не знаете, как работать с WinForms, то корректней задать отдельный вопрос.

Comment: Именно момент считывание файла настроек и открытия форм.конструкция switch case я думаю использовать